# iOS: As of 2013 what is the best way to scan barcodes and QR codes?

Tags: ios, ios7, barcode, qr-code

I'm finding older questions and answers on this topic. But I gather in iOS 7 there is a framework for QR codes. Does it support barcodes too? And if I want to support earlier devices, what is the library that is considered the best as of now?

Comment: AVCaptureMetaDataOutput from AVFoundation

Comment: http://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=453

Answer (score 11):

iOS 7 introduced QR code and Barcode reading support in `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`. It can read the following formats:

- UPC-A
- UPC-E
- Code 39
- Code 39 mod 43
- Code 93
- Code 128
- EAN-8
- EAN-13
- Aztec
- PDF417
- QR

To implement it you need to add an `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` with the object types you want to scan for to an `AVCaptureSession`.

```
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *metadataOutput= [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[self.session addOutput:metadataOutput];
[metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[metadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code]];
```

And implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

The different metadata objects you can listen for are listed here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A popular library for previous versions of iOS was ZBar although I know a lot of users had issues with ZBar when trying to use it with iOS 7. This may have been fixed by now though.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net